# Angular 2 | Can't use property binding on routed component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Good day,

Can anyone tell me what is/are the alternative way to bind property on a routed component? it seems @input() decorator is not working on routed component.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code? Though someone already gave an answer, it would be more helpful if you can provide your code

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: you can refer to my another question here. what i want is i want to bind class property to a child component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817467/angular-2-i-cant-bind-property-from-another-class?noredirect=1#comment76615953_44817467

Answer (score 0):

Try using router params. So, in your router config, have the router path to your component(considered "MyComponent") like this;

`routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'mycomponent/:myParam', component: MyComponent}
]`.

And pass the actual value to the router in your anchor tag in HTML like;

`<a [routerLink]="['/mycomponent', paramValue]">
  Link to MyComponent
</a>`

or in your parent component, navigate to MyComponent programmatically;

`this.router.navigate(['/mycomponent', paramValue]);`

And in your component(MyComponent), import the ActivatedRoute from angular router, which provides a **params** Observable, and subscribe to that observable in the ngOnInit method. So your **MyComponent** should look something like this;

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  template: '<div>My Component - Param Value {{myParamValue}}</div> '
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
 myParamValue: any;
 private subscribe: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe= this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.myParamValue = params['myParam'];
    });
  } 

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Read More [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html)

Comment: is this same with property binding? so in this example you are sending the myParamValue to the activated router link? to where the route you are currently?

Comment: Property binding applies when you have a template property value that should be bound to a component property. If the data you have to pass to the component is something like an id, you can use this method. Otherwise, use a common service to share the data between these components