# Angular 6: Input with initial value without two way data binding

Tags: angular

I want to give my `input` a initial value. It should be without two way databinding so not `[(ngModel)]="categories.name"`. I have tried this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onEditCategoie(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kategorie Name" name="name" [value]="categorie.name" ngModel required>
    </div>
<form>
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One way data binding in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157317/one-way-data-binding-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one way data binding just use

```
[ngModel]="categories.name"
```